# Reading from Text file but only store specific parts

Tags: java

I am trying to store details of a Car with its x coordinate and its y coordinate from a text document. here is what the text document looks like (the '760' is on another line intentionally)

I am wondering if there is a way to read the file and just store the car name and x & y coordinates. I already have a constructor set up to take a name, x & y. I also have this Scanner set up:

```
File file;
            file = new File("CarInfo.txt");

            try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String carTab = sc.next();
        // Looking for tag 'Car'
        if (!carTab.equals("Car:")) continue;

        if (!sc.hasNext()) {
            break;
        }

        String car = sc.next();
        if (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            continue;
        }
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        if (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            break;
        }
        int y = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(car + " " + x + " " + y);
    }



} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File not found");
}
```

I've looked around and seen people using `.next();` but I cant get it to work.

Edit:

Error Received from code (Keqiang Li):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at traingui.code.TrainGui$1.run(TrainGui.java:37)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Since _"the '120' is on another line intentionally"_ is that an "error" and can it be corrected?  Are there any other abnormalities about the file?  What you _could_ do is treat the file as a stream, where newlines are insignificant (treat as any other whitespace) and parse a series of 4 "fields" — fixed `Station:`, whitespace, _StationName_ whitespace, _x_, whitespace, _y_

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("StationInfo.txt");

    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file)) {
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String stationTab = sc.next();
            // Looking for tag 'Station:'
            if (!stationTab.equals("Station:")) continue;

            if (!sc.hasNext()) {
                break;
            }

            String station = sc.next();
            if (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
                continue;
            }
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            if (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
                continue;
            }
            int y = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(station + " " + x + " " + y);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have received this error from that code, but cant see whats causing it? (included the error in the code above)

Comment: @Safa That's an error I was talking about in my answer since your file might be malformed. So you need to handle if a double is expected but something else show up in the file. This of course will throw an mismatch exception. More malformed possibilities in your file, the more code you need to add here to handle them.

Comment: Will I add this in the catch section then?

Comment: @Safa Please see update. Basically, each time before you scan, you need to make sure it's the proper type. If it's not, just skip it and try find the next station.

Comment: I see, thank you. Sorry to be a pain but no errors now, but not printing out to the output!

Comment: @Safa Make sure you're not reading from file 'test.txt', that's something I have on my computer, change the name to your file name.

Comment: @Safa I saw what happened... You changed the tag in your file to 'Place' while in my code I'm using 'Station'...

Comment: no, my code i have on my computer is still 'Station'. is it not due to the whitespace that it is breaking??

Comment: I copied the file content you included in your question with 'Station' tag and it worked on my computer. Can you make sure you're using that file? Do some debug you will find what's going on.

Comment: Ive changed the code above to what you have told me. it still doesnt print out with that code? can you see anything wrong with it??

Comment: @Safa Change the last `break` to `continue` since I changed my code.

Comment: @Safa And either put your file into your project folder or change the code to read from the path of your file. I saw you were using '/Users/Documents..`, something like that.

Comment: Ya i've done all that, i changed the file name to make sure that it is locating the file and that is all fine. for some reason it is still just not printing it out to the output!

Comment: @Safa Debug your program might be my only suggestion then.

Comment: @Safa Hi Safa, I saw you posted it in another question. My best guess is lines in your file doesn't actually start with 'Station:'. So, please add `System.out.println(stationTag);` before `if (!stationTab.equals("Station:"))` and see what is actually printed out. I guess it's not "Station:". Pay attention that it should be exactly "Station:". I guess you might use lower case for the 'S' in your file or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job, taking into account that your values can be split across two lines.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StationTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("StationInfo.txt");
        String token1 = "";
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                String[] acceptedValues = new String[3];
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                String[] values = line.split(" ");

                for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
                    acceptedValues[i - 1] = values[i];
                }

                if (values.length < 4) {
                    String nextLine = sc.nextLine();
                    String[] nextLineValues = nextLine.split(" ");
                    for (int i = 1; i <= acceptedValues.length + 1 - values.length; i++) {
                        acceptedValues[values.length + i - 2] = nextLineValues[i - 1];
                    }
                }
            }

            // Do as you wish with these values, setting them in your model class.
            System.out.println("Name: " + acceptedValues[0]);
            System.out.println("X: " + acceptedValues[1]);
            System.out.println("Y: " + acceptedValues[2]);

            sc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem with a regex:

```
File file = new File("StationInfo.txt");

    String line = "";

    try {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

            String name;
            double x;
            double y;

            // find next line
            String temp = sc.nextLine();
            try {
                Double.parseDouble(temp);
                line += " " + temp;
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                line = temp;
            }

            String regex = "^(\\w+:)\\s(\\w+)\\s(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)";

            if(line.matches(regex)) {
                name = line.replaceAll(regex, "$2");
                x = Double.parseDouble(line.replaceAll(regex, "$3"));
                y = Double.parseDouble(line.replaceAll(regex, "$4"));
                System.out.println("Name = " + name + ", x = " + x + ", y = " + y);
            }

            // TrainNetwork.newStation.addStation(token1);
        }
        sc.close();



        // System.out.println(TrainNetwork.newStation);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }
```

Here the regex find the different parts of the string and stores the data in 3 variables named name, x and y.

EDIT: now the code recognise if there is a carriage return and will work also with the last line of data.
And if you want to add more than one whitespace between the words make sure to change the regex with this `String regex = "^(\\w+:)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)";`

You early changed the "Station:" into "Place:" so I assumed that you doesn't care of the first word but if you want to accept the string only if it start with "Station:" just change the regex with `String regex = "^(Station:)\\s(\\w+)\\s(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)";`

Comment: I commented the `TrainNetwork.newStation.addStation()` thing because I don't have the code and I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create another Object for stations and then store each Station object in an ArrayList in the same file that you have the File Reading code in:

**Station Object**

```
public class Station {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Double> coords;

    public Station(String name, ArrayList<Double> coords){
        this.name = name;
        this.coords = coords;
    }

}
```

**Your Code Modified**

```
    File file = new File("StationInfo.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    ArrayList<Station> stationObj = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Double> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    String stationName = "";

    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String token = sc.next();

        if (!token.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Station:")) {     
            try{
                temp.add(Double.parseDouble(token));
            } catch (Exception e){
                stationName = token;
            }
        }

        // The below will work for when you have 1 coordinate or both coordinates.

        if(!stationName.equals("") && !stationName.equalsIgnoreCase("Station:") && !temp.isEmpty() && (!sc.hasNextDouble() || !sc.hasNextInt())){
            stationObj.add(new Station(stationName, temp));
            temp = new ArrayList<>();
            stationName = "";
        }

    }
```

If you debug and look at the `stationObj` Arraylist, you will see each station and it's coordinates stored in each Station object within the list.